# asp.net gridview template column

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net gridview, I am placing a template column which displays an image.

Inside the template column I added an image control, and it successfully displaying the images from the database. I am also using paging.

Paging also happening but when I do paging images are not coming in the gridview in proper order for example first three pages it diplays suppose a.jpg, b.jpg,c.jpg and when I click on page number it repeats the same picture instead of remaining pictures, i am using `if(!ispostback)` in the load event also. please help me out.

my code in page load event is:

da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from t1", con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        path = Server.MapPath(@"~\images");
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

```
    ASCIIEncoding asc = new ASCIIEncoding();
    int j = GridView1.Rows.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {

        GridViewRow r=GridView1.Rows[i];
        b = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["photo"];
        string name = asc.GetString(b);
        Image img = (Image)r.FindControl("Image1");
        img.ImageUrl = path + @"\" + name;

    }
    }
```

and my code in paging event is

GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        ASCIIEncoding asc = new ASCIIEncoding();
int j = GridView1.Rows.Count;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {

        GridViewRow r=GridView1.Rows[i];
        b = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["photo"];
        string name = asc.GetString(b);
        Image img = (Image)r.FindControl("Image1");
        img.ImageUrl = path + @"\" + name;

    }
```

thank in advance
sangita

Comment: can you post code you are using for data fetching-binding with grid and paging?

Answer (score 0):

When you write your paging method you still need to re-query the datasource and rebind your gridview (along with setting the PageIndex).

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have only the image name stored in the database you can do this in the Image Control in you template column

set the databinding for the image url as

```
String.Format("images/{0}",Eval("photo"))
```

and as boon has said

> When you write your paging method you
>   still need to re-query the datasource
>   and rebind your gridview (along with
>   setting the PageIndex).

you can declare a method that fetches the records from the database as

```
protected void fillData()
    {
      da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from t1", con);
      ds = new DataSet(); 
      da.Fill(ds);
      GridView1.DataSource = ds; 
      GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and use it to bind data to your gridview
and in your paging_indexChanging function

```
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
fillData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the image paths in pagination. If the images paths are same, then disable the browser cache.